# Sum Before Crossing Value x

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm having trouble answering the following question:

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, .... be uniform [0,1] iid RVs. Define:

$t(x) = min(n>0:X_1+X_2+....X_n > x)$. Find $P(t(x)>2).$

To get an idea of what $t(x)$ is doing -- it's basically adding uniform random variables until it crosses a threshold. I think it has to do something with first step conditioning. But Im not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $\{t(x)>2\}$ means the sum of 2 iid uniform RVs is less than $x$, and  $P(X_1+X_2<x)=\int_0^{min(1,x)}\int_0^{min(1,x-x_1)}dx_2dx_1.$

Comment: how do you see that connection?

Comment: $X_1+X_2<x$ means you need more than 2 of the $X_i$ to exceed $x$, which means $t(x)>2$.